# How is the do ... end loop in slack-ruby-bot sample code structured?

Tags: ruby, syntax, bots, slack

I'm very new to ruby. I want to build a slack bot in ruby using [slack-ruby-bot](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot). In their tutorial, they have the following code:

```
require 'slack-ruby-bot'

class PongBot < SlackRubyBot::Bot
  command 'ping' do |client, data, match|
    client.say(text: 'pong', channel: data.channel)
  end
end

PongBot.run
```

My question is as follows:

1. What does the `command` do? Is it a function that takes in `'ping'`? Why isn't there a `def` for in-class methods just like in other languages?
2. This might be something I can write on my own once I understand this sample code, but what should I write if I want to extract urls from commands users type into a channel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command` is a class method of `SlackRubyBot::Commands::Base`, which `PongBot` gets by inheritance through `SlackRubyBot::Bot`. As a class method, it can be invoked in the class context. So yes, it is a method that takes `'ping'` as an argument.

You can use `def` to define methods, of course. `command` does not actually define any methods. What it does is it creates a regular expression to match your command and enters it (and the accompanying code block) into a data structure against which traffic will be filtered later.

If you want to match arbitrary regular expressions in arbitrary text in channel, follow the section on [generic routing](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-bot#generic-routing), using the `match` method (for single match) or `scan` method (for all matches). Something like this (untested):

```
class URLBot < SlackRubyBot::Bot
  # adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/240443
  URL_RE = /([a-z](?:[-a-z0-9\+\.])*:(?:\/\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:])*@)?(?:\[(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){6}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){5}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){4}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){3}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){2}(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3})|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::[0-9a-f]{1,4}|(?:(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:){0,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4})?::)|v[0-9a-f]+[-a-z0-9\._~!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:]+)\]|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=@])*)(?::[0-9]*)?(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|\/(?:(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*)?|(?:(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))+)(?:\/(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@]))*)*|(?!(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])))(?:\?(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\u{E000}-\u{F8FF}\u{F0000}-\u{FFFFD}\u{100000}-\u{10FFFD}\/\?])*)?(?:\#(?:(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[-a-z0-9\._~\u{A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}\u{10000}-\u{1FFFD}\u{20000}-\u{2FFFD}\u{30000}-\u{3FFFD}\u{40000}-\u{4FFFD}\u{50000}-\u{5FFFD}\u{60000}-\u{6FFFD}\u{70000}-\u{7FFFD}\u{80000}-\u{8FFFD}\u{90000}-\u{9FFFD}\u{A0000}-\u{AFFFD}\u{B0000}-\u{BFFFD}\u{C0000}-\u{CFFFD}\u{D0000}-\u{DFFFD}\u{E1000}-\u{EFFFD}!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=:@])|[\/\?])*)?)/i

  scan URL_RE do |client, data, urls|
    # do something with `urls`
  end
end
```

Comment: "command does not actually define any methods. " - I think he thought that `command` invocation itself is some kind of weird method definition where `def` is omitted.